# Log File to Keyword Relationship Output

Tags: php, mysql, sql, logging

I have a log file we will call this log.txt and it has about 50,000 lines in it.

I want to setup a SQL Database that has certain keywords in it say like Car,Truck,Error Code and so on. Is there anyway that I can run that log.txt file against a SQL Database and get output just for these keywords that are in the SQL database?

Comment: Yes, you can do that.

Comment: How would this be done? Is there a site you can point me to. Btw I gave you some points for that. Made me laugh

Comment: Your question is too vague and therefore too broad to provide a meaningful answer. All modern programming languages can connect to databases and open text files, therefore all of them can be used to achieve what you want.